# VB.net SendKeys to send keys combined not using "ALT" or "CTRL", like "{INS}(S)"

Tags: vb.net, combinations, sendkeys

I need to send the keystroke combination <kbd>INSERT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> keys simultaneously but it seems that VB only leaves use key combinations with <kbd>ALT</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>.

Is there any way to do it?

I've tried:

```
{INS}(S)
{INS}S
```

and many others, but this does not work.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Insert is not a modifier key like Shift/Alt/Ctrl.  There isn't any way to simulate it being held-down with SendKeys while you send S.  You'll have to pinvoke SendInput() instead.

Comment: Thank you Hans, I will try SendInput()

Comment: Hello, I has used SendInput() and it's works but... it leave "ins key" pressed... KEYEVENTF_KEYUP doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It does. See:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Had you tried "{INS}(S)" ?

**UPDATE**

I did the following test:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Click
    SendKeys.Send("{Ins}S")
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    MsgBox(e.KeyCode)
End Sub
```

Look, I received in the KeyDown event 2 codes: the INS and the "S"
The problem is about the KeyDown event will file TWO TIMES, I mean, you cannot get the INS-S code with ONE reading.

So, you must consider have a FRIEND/PUBLIC variable to receive both codes and only after this, make the critic about these.

Good luck

Comment: David, I have tried "{INS}(S)" and more combinations without success... I will try with SendInput()... Thanks!

Comment: Hello David, thanks for your interest. I can't do it because I need to send the combination to another third party program running in background and I need to send the keys with one reading...

Comment: @jakama, the SendKeys will send both {INS} and the "S" keys, but it will fire exactly at the time user press the INS and the S (two fired events) - and it´s logical since user must press 2 keys. I mean, if the third party could check this, your program will function 100%, otherwise, you just have to detect (and "buffer") each key separately. Anyway, you´re welcome. Good luck.